# sum of squares of the first n primes

Tags: primes, number-theory

I saw on this site some time ago an asymptotic formula for the sum of the squares of the first n primes, but I'm unable to find it now. We have for the sum of the squares of the first n integers: (n*n+1*(2n+1))/6, but this doesn't help me when primes are substituted for integers. Is there a reference for this result?

Comment: Post it on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This might be better asked of math stack exchange. The topic here on SO is programming questions.

Comment: BTW, you can rely on the fact that all prime numbers except for 2 and 3 are of the form `6k±1`, and use it in order to calculate an upper bound on the sum of their squares.

Comment: The formula seems the sum of square of first n natural number.